# What is this short, wide band signal?

Tags: modes, signal-identification

I've observed a signal I'm unfamiliar with, and am wondering what it might be:

[image]

The period of time it lasted is 5 seconds, and it occurs irregularly.  You might be able to see it too via [WebSDR](http://hackgreensdr.org:8901/).

How would I discover what type of signal this is, generally, and does anyone know off the top of their head what it is?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is Digital Radio Mondale (DRM), but given that it's only five seconds long each time - exactly - I'm not sure.  It does consume the same 10kHz bandwidth, and has some pattern similarities.

Here's one resource for visual signal identification: http://www.rtl-sdr.com/signal-identification-guide/

Digital modes are given a pretty thorough treatment with included waterfall signatures here:

http://hfradio.org.uk/html/digital_modes.html